# DHTMLX Scheduler - Calendar view - set focus to config.mark_now

Tags: scheduler, dhtmlx

When loading the calendar, I have divided the hours into intervals of 30 mins each.

This is my initial configuration.

```
    scheduler.locale.labels.unit_tab = "Resources";
    scheduler.config.hour_date = "%h:%i %A";
    scheduler.config.hour_size_px = 88;
    scheduler.config.mark_now = true;
    scheduler.locale.labels.section_custom = "Assigned to";
    scheduler.config.separate_short_events = true;
    scheduler.config.drag_move = false;
    scheduler.config.drag_resize = false;
```

Due to the 30 mins, my calendar has a scroll bar. The default calendar shows only about 6.5 hrs. So if the current time is 3 PM, the mark_now line is off the view. How do I set focus to the current time and have the current time or mark_now be in the horizontal center of the display?

I am learning dhtmlx and may not be able to answer all queries so would appreciate any guidance. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add something like next

```
scheduler.config.scroll_hour = (new Date).getHours();
```

It will configure scheduler to scroll day or week view to the current hour.

Comment: Nope, this does not seem to be working. Here is the code snippet I have: json = JSON.parse(result);
    scheduler.parse(json.events, "json");
    scheduler.config.mark_now = true;
    scheduler.config.scroll_hour = (new Date).getHours(); scheduler.init('scheduler_here', new Date(), "unit"); scheduler.updateView();